# How can List<DerivedClass> be assigned to IEnumerable<BaseClass> parameter?

Tags: c#, list

I understand that the List<> of derived class cannot be directly assigned to List<> of base class. But how does it allow assigning the same List<> of derived class to an IEnumerable<> type of base class parameter.

```
public class Base 
{}

public class Derived : Base 
{}

public class Test
{
   // inside some method...
   List<Derived> someElements;
   ReadElements(someElements);

   public void ReadElements(List<Base> elements) // this throws compile error
   {...} 

   public void ReadElements(IEnumerable<Base> elements) // this one works
   {...}
}
```

I know that the `List` is an implementation of `IEnumerable` and support indexing and modifying elements, but I don't seem to understand this part? Can someone please explain?
Thanks.

Comment: See [Covariance and Contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the declaration of `IEnumerable<T>` [is in fact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx):

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

...and the `out` bit means that `T` is covariant and accepts subtypes.

Whereas the declaration of `List<T>` has no variance annotation and therefore the `T` is invariant.

Answer (score 2):

`IList` and `List` do not define their `T` as `out`, while `IEnumerable` does. `List` is a class so can't have `out`, and `IList` does not define `out` because it accepts inputs of type `T`.

Put a simpler way you can only get back `T` from `IEnumerable`, but you can put in `T` to `IList`, because of this `IEnumerable` doesn't care if you are less specific, but `IList` does. (In fact it has to, see @ChrisShain's answer for a link to how covariance and contravariance work).

Answer (score 2):

Consider this code, which on its own is perfectly legal:

```
public void AddElements(List<Base> elements)
{
    Base item = new Base();
    elements.Add(item);
}
```

But what happens if you call it like this:

```
List<Derived> elements = new List<Derived>;
AddElements(elements);
```

The class `Base` does not inherit from `Derived` and therefore cannot be added to the `elements` list.  It's a potential problem, therefore illegal.

On the other hand, `IEnumerable<Base>` only provides methods to read the collection, not write to it, so the above contradiction cannot occur.

Answer (score 1):

Because IEnumerable is Covariant for the type parameter T: http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2010/01/10/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-4.0.aspx